# How to write a simplified if condition

Tags: if-statement

I have three parameters value1, value2, value3 and I am supposed to check for four different values in them. Is there a simplified way to write the equivalent condition in Java or in JavaScript :

```
      if ((value1 == 11) || (value1 == 88) || (value1 == 66) || (value1 == 33) || 
          (value2 == 11) || (value2 == 88) || (value2 == 66) || (value2 == 33) || 
          (value3 == 11) || (value3 == 88) || (value3 == 66) || (value3 == 33)) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is 3 different versions of the function which validates given condition:

```java
static final int[] SORTED_VALUES = new int[] {11, 33, 66, 88};

static boolean isAtLeastOneEquals1(final int value1, final int value2, final int value3) {
    for (final int i : SORTED_VALUES)
        if ((i == value1) || (i == value2) || (i == value3))
            return true;
    return false;
}

static boolean isAtLeastOneEquals2(final int value1, final int value2, final int value3) {
    return (Arrays.binarySearch(SORTED_VALUES, value1) >= 0)
            || (Arrays.binarySearch(SORTED_VALUES, value2) >= 0)
            || (Arrays.binarySearch(SORTED_VALUES, value3) >= 0);
}

static boolean isAtLeastOneEquals3(final int... values) {
    for (final int v : values)
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(SORTED_VALUES, v) >= 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

personally I prefer 2nd one, but 3rd is more universal